# Crash on Google Play Games Sign In (Device Specific) (Galaxy Nexus)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am getting some device specific crash when trying to sign in to Google Play Games. While most devices work fine, there are a few that will crash and I get a message of  "Unfortunately, XYZ has stopped"

My device is Galaxy Nexus as it appears from the title.

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1693810/5651923/8758ad52-9671-11e4-84ba-cd705da76bb7.png

```
I/Unity(6202):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 01/13/15 14:51:02 -06:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Activate() (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:129)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGamesProxy:activate() (at /Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:123)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGamesProxy:authenticate() (at /Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:138)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGamesProxy:sign_in() (at /Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:83)
I/Unity(6202): WidgetGooglePlayGames:on_click()
I/Unity(6202):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 01/13/15 14:51:02 -06:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Activate() (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:131)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGamesProxy:activate() (at /Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:123)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGamesProxy:authenticate() (at /Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:138)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGamesProxy:sign_in() (at /Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:83)
I/Unity(6202): WidgetGooglePlayGames:on_click()
I/Unity(6202):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 01/13/15 14:51:02 -06:00 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:193)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:170)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser:Authenticate(Action`1) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesLocalUser.cs:44)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGamesProxy:authenticate() (at /Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper
I/Unity(6202):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 01/13/15 14:51:02 -06:00 DEBUG: Creating real IPlayGamesClient
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesClientFactory:GetPlatformPlayGamesClient(PlayGamesClientConfiguration) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/PlayGamesClientFactory.cs:32)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:194)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:170)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser:Authenticate(Action`1) (at /Project/
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/GamesUnitySDK(6202): Performing Android initialization of the GPG SDK
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
E/GamesNativeSDK(6202): Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.NativeSdkEntryPoints" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.company.project/app_.gpg.classloader/4da25210572e7e07ea67142ded62c42e.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].
D/dalvikvm(6202): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1409K, 10% free 13331K/14776K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
W/PopupManager(6202): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
A/libc(6202): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 6342 (main)
I/Unity(6202):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 01/13/15 14:51:02 -06:00 DEBUG: Entering state: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:EnterState(State) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:333)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:.ctor(RealtimeManager, RealTimeMultiplayerListener) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:304)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:GetTerminatedSession() (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:42)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMul
I/Unity(6202):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 01/13/15 14:51:02 -06:00 DEBUG: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.State:OnStateEntered() (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:500)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:EnterState(State) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:334)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:.ctor(RealtimeManager, RealTimeMultiplayerListener) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:304)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerCl
I/Unity(6202):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 01/13/15 14:51:03 -06:00 DEBUG: Entering state: ShutdownState
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:EnterState(State) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:333)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:GetTerminatedSession() (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:43)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:.ctor(NativeClient, RealtimeManager) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:38)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient:InitializeGameS
I/Unity(6202):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 01/13/15 14:51:03 -06:00 DEBUG: ShutdownState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity(6202): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.State:OnStateEntered() (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:500)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:EnterState(State) (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:334)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:GetTerminatedSession() (at /Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:43)
I/Unity(6202): GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:.ctor(NativeClient, 
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so 0x41f251a8
D/dalvikvm(6202): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f251a8
I/DEBUG(123): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG(123): Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.3/JWR66Y/776638:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG(123): Revision: '9'
I/DEBUG(123): pid: 6202, tid: 6342, name: main  >>> com.company.project <<<
I/DEBUG(123): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
I/AudioFlinger(128): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4098) from active list on thread 0x40b83008
I/DEBUG(123):     r0 00000027  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 deadbaad
I/DEBUG(123):     r4 00000000  r5 6900bde4  r6 00000000  r7 6900be1c
I/DEBUG(123):     r8 6a349bc1  r9 68f0c000  sl 6900bf00  fp 676d03e0
I/DEBUG(123):     ip 00000001  sp 6900bde0  lr 401d0f93  pc 401ce4e8  cpsr 600f0030
I/DEBUG(123):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d4  2c5d2272616a2e65  d5  694c65766974616e
I/DEBUG(123):     d6  7269447972617262  d7  42c800004b504c10
I/DEBUG(123):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d16 3ff0000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d18 bb360b6100000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 00000000bca237c3
I/DEBUG(123):     d22 3f7fffe0bf800008  d23 3f800000bf7aee42
I/DEBUG(123):     d24 000000003adb2f17  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d26 bb360b6100000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(123):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 00000000bca237c3
I/DEBUG(123):     d30 3f7fffe0bf800008  d31 3f800000bf7aee42
I/DEBUG(123):     scr 20000017
I/DEBUG(123): backtrace:
I/DEBUG(123):     #00  pc 0001e4e8  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG(123):     #01  pc 0001c510  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG(123):     #02  pc 0010b285  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so
I/DEBUG(123):     #03  pc 000fecbf  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so
I/DEBUG(123):     #04  pc 0000e7e4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_once+108)
I/DEBUG(123):     #05  pc 000febcf  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so (__cxa_get_globals+18)
I/DEBUG(123):     #06  pc 000fe54d  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so (__cxa_throw+12)
I/DEBUG(123): stack:
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bda0  65f1fcc8  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bda4  0000002b  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bda8  401f8170  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdac  58c76388  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdb0  00000091  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdb4  401cff75  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush+56)
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdb8  401f8220  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdbc  401fb540  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdc0  00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdc4  401d0f93  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+34)
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdc8  401d023d  /system/lib/libc.so (_cleanup)
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdcc  6900bde4  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdd0  00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdd4  6900be1c  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdd8  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bddc  00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     #00  6900bde0  401f81c4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bde4  fffffbdf  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bde8  0000000a  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdec  00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdf0  401f81c4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdf4  401fbd8c  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdf8  0000000a  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900bdfc  401f81c4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be00  6a34ac9d  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be04  401cc514  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_clone)
I/DEBUG(123):     #01  6900be08  000018c6  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be0c  6a357289  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so
I/DEBUG(123):     #02  6900be10  6a3cfeb8  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be14  6900be2c  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be18  6a3cfebc  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be1c  6900be38  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be20  676d03e0  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be24  6a34acc3  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-1/libgpg.so
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be28  6a3cfebc  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be2c  fffed391  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be30  00000001  
I/DEBUG(123):          6900be34  00000000  
I/DEBUG(123): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bdc4 401d0f93 401d023d 6900bde4 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bdd4 6900be1c df0027ad 00000000 401f81c4  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bde4 fffffbdf 0000000a 00000000 401f81c4  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bdf4 401fbd8c 0000000a 401f81c4 6a34ac9d  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be04 401cc514 000018c6 6a357289 6a3cfeb8  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be14 6900be2c 6a3cfebc 6900be38 676d03e0  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be24 6a34acc3 6a3cfebc fffed391 00000001  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be34 00000000 6900be58 401be7e8 690f5c50  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be44 0000411c 6a3cad00 6a34abd3 690f5c50  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be54 690f5c50 6900be6c 6a34a551 0000000b  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be64 690f5c50 6a3b907e 6900be84 5f02bcc8  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be74 6a349f25 68a63880 00003f0c 6a2b5279  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be84 6900be98 676d03e0 6a349e75 68a63880  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be94 676d03e0 68a63880 6a2b5285 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bea4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900beb4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123): memory near r7:
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bdfc 401f81c4 6a34ac9d 401cc514 000018c6  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be0c 6a357289 6a3cfeb8 6900be2c 6a3cfebc  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be1c 6900be38 676d03e0 6a34acc3 6a3cfebc  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be2c fffed391 00000001 00000000 6900be58  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be3c 401be7e8 690f5c50 0000411c 6a3cad00  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be4c 6a34abd3 690f5c50 690f5c50 6900be6c  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be5c 6a34a551 0000000b 690f5c50 6a3b907e  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be6c 6900be84 5f02bcc8 6a349f25 68a63880  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be7c 00003f0c 6a2b5279 6900be98 676d03e0  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be8c 6a349e75 68a63880 676d03e0 68a63880  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be9c 6a2b5285 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900beac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bebc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900becc 6900bf00 6900bf00 676d03e0 6a2b5279  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bedc 68a63880 5f02bcc8 401bca5c 68a63880  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900beec 00000000 00100000 68a63880 00000078  
I/DEBUG(123): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349ba0 f0044620 bf00f891 00082232 ffffff90  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349bb0 466fb580 ff00f002 fab2f001 bf00bd80  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349bc0 466fb580 fef8f002 bf00bd80 4bf0e92d  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349bd0 481d4681 af034d1d 46884478 2010182e  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349be0 fb7af000 7b304604 0f01f010 4818d111  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349bf0 44284478 f001300c b150f88b 49164815  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c00 182a4478 30084408 f1026090 f001000c  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c10 4812f8d5 44284478 0208f100 46494620  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c20 f7ff4643 480efdc3 4478490e 58094a0e  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c30 46204402 fc84f000 46204605 fbd8f000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c40 f0044628 bf00f841 000821c0 00003efc  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c50 000821a8 00082198 ffff6954 00082184  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c60 0008216e ffffff94 fff7de25 bf004770  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c70 466fb580 fa54f001 bf00bd80 466fb580  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c80 fa4ef001 bf00bd80 466fb580 fa48f001  
I/DEBUG(123):     6a349c90 bf00bd80 6801b580 2900466f bd80bf08  
I/DEBUG(123): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0bfe0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0bff0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c060 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c070 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c080 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c090 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c0a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c0b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c0c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     68f0c0d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bee0 5f02bcc8 401bca5c 68a63880 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bef0 00100000 68a63880 00000078 401bcbd8  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf00 6900bf00 676d03e0 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf10 00000000 38d76640 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf20 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf30 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf40 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf50 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf60 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf70 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf80 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bf90 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bfa0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bfb0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bfc0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bfd0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG(123):     676d03c0 00000000 00000002 00000002 00000002  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d03d0 00000002 000000e4 00000024 0000024b  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d03e0 6978b080 00000000 00000001 68f0c000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d03f0 00100000 00001000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0400 000018c6 00000001 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0410 00000000 00000000 00000000 6900bf00  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0420 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0430 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0440 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0450 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0460 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0470 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0480 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d0490 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d04a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     676d04b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bdc0 00000000 401d0f93 401d023d 6900bde4  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bdd0 00000000 6900be1c df0027ad 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bde0 401f81c4 fffffbdf 0000000a 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bdf0 401f81c4 401fbd8c 0000000a 401f81c4  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be00 6a34ac9d 401cc514 000018c6 6a357289  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be10 6a3cfeb8 6900be2c 6a3cfebc 6900be38  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be20 676d03e0 6a34acc3 6a3cfebc fffed391  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be30 00000001 00000000 6900be58 401be7e8  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be40 690f5c50 0000411c 6a3cad00 6a34abd3  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be50 690f5c50 690f5c50 6900be6c 6a34a551  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be60 0000000b 690f5c50 6a3b907e 6900be84  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be70 5f02bcc8 6a349f25 68a63880 00003f0c  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be80 6a2b5279 6900be98 676d03e0 6a349e75  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900be90 68a63880 676d03e0 68a63880 6a2b5285  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900bea0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123):     6900beb0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(123): code around pc:
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce4c8 461ce00b 2b006823 e026d1fb b12468e4  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce4d8 21014a18 6011447a 4b1247a0 24002027  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce4e8 f7fc7018 2106ee42 e898f7fe 5180f04f  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce4f8 a9029104 94022006 9403460a ec44f7fd  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce508 46224629 f7fd2002 f7fcec50 2106ee2e  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce518 e884f7fe f7fc2001 6960eada d1dc2800  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce528 bf00e7d4 deadbaad 00029b30 ffffff9c  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce538 0002cdc0 0002cda4 2400b510 aa04b088  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce548 46699002 94014620 94039400 eb92f7fd  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce558 db0642a0 b1139b07 1c419806 98069106  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce568 4620e000 bd10b008 4b1eb40e b082b5f0  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce578 447b491d f107af00 585e021c f8522101  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce588 68354b04 f852607d 31015b04 d1fa2d00  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce598 320e008a 0507f022 0220f107 0d05ebad  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce5a8 f107603a 46690224 9400466d 4c04f852  
I/DEBUG(123):     401ce5b8 f8453204 2c004f04 f8dfd1f8 f853c030  
I/DEBUG(123): code around lr:
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0f70 4a0e4b0d e92d447b 260041f0 4680589c  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0f80 686768a5 f9b5e007 2b00300c 4628dd02  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0f90 430647c0 3f013554 6824d5f5 d1ef2c00  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0fa0 e8bd4630 bf0081f0 00027060 ffffffc4  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0fb0 43f0e92d fb01461e 4b16f502 4916460f  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0fc0 447bb087 aa014614 20019001 95029203  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0fd0 90049505 681a585b b1124698 f0094630  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0fe0 4630fd26 f7ffa903 4681fe9c 0000f8d8  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d0ff0 4630b110 fd28f009 0f00f1b9 9c05d005  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d1000 1b284639 eb30f017 46204604 e8bdb007  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d1010 bf0083f0 00027012 ffffff60 46036842  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d1020 60411e51 da012900 bb9ef000 f8126802  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d1030 601a0b01 00004770 4a104b0f b570447b  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d1040 589b4604 461e6819 f009b109 6860fcf0  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d1050 60651e45 da042d00 f0004620 4605fb85  
I/DEBUG(123):     401d1060 6822e003 5b01f812 68336022 4620b113  
I/DEBUG(123): memory map around fault addr deadbaad:
I/DEBUG(123):     bee2a000-bee4b000 rw- [stack]
I/DEBUG(123):     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG(123):     ffff0000-ffff1000 r-x [vectors]
W/ActivityManager(370):   Force finishing activity com.company.project/com.prime31.UnityPlayerActivity
W/InputDispatcher(370): channel '422e2180 com.company.project/com.prime31.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(370): channel '422e2180 com.company.project/com.prime31.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
D/dalvikvm(370): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1395K, 24% free 20298K/26524K, paused 62ms, total 63ms
W/InputDispatcher(370): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '422e2180 com.company.project/com.prime31.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
I/WindowState(370): WIN DEATH: Window{422e2180 u0 com.company.project/com.prime31.UnityPlayerActivity}
I/WindowState(370): WIN DEATH: Window{421d3ad0 u0 SurfaceView}
W/ActivityManager(370): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager(370): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager(370):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:635)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:990)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3834)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3766)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8344)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8221)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:8900)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:8455)
W/ActivityManager(370):     at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
D/Zygote(126): Process 6202 terminated by signal (11)
```

Comment: assuming you're using google's unity plugin, you might have some luck posting this on the github page: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues although they don't seem that responsive. :(